# Загрузка файла через форму

Tags: php

Возникла следующая проблема. 
Загружаются 2 картинки.
Все встает на этой функции.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['goodsImage']['tmp_name'], $kernelVars['goodsDir'] . $imageName);
```

Ошибка

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(/images/goods/2013_3.jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in 

move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/tmp/phpQAmkg5' to '/images/goods/2013_3.jpg' in
```

Содержание $_FILES

```
array(2) { ["goodsImage"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(5) "3.jpg" ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg"   
["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpQAmkg5" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(32111) } ["goodsImageNew"]=> array(5)  
{ ["name"]=> string(5) "4.jpg" ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phprgw9UP" 
["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(48431) } }
```

Comment: вроде все ясно написано? у вас есть путь `/images/goods/` доступный для записи? сомневаюсь что-то. Добавьте к пути назначения полный путь к папке сайта.

Comment: я везде 777 поставил, и путь полный - никакого эффекта.

Comment: А путь такой есть?

Comment: да, $kernelVars['goodsDir'] . $imageName = "/var/www/example.com/images/goods/" - Достаточно же права на запись сделать для images и goods?

Comment: вам же пишет, что нет пути `/images/goods/` куда вы пытаетесь записать файл, а вы пишите про `/var/www/example.com/images/goods` вы осознаете, что это разные пути совсем?

Comment: `/images/goods/2013_3.jpg` - путь от корня же

Comment: Путь полный я сделал после первого комментария, 1 букву пропустил в пути, - все заработало, спасибо всем.